# CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your function : context deadline exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Getting this error when connecting cloud sql instance within cloud function (python).
Earlier there were no such issues.

```
import os
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        user=os.environ.get('user'),
        passwd=os.environ.get('password'),
        database=os.environ.get('database'),
        host=os.environ.get('host'),
        pool_name=os.environ.get('pool_name'), pool_size=1,
        unix_socket=os.environ.get('unix_socket')
)
```

cursor=cnx.cursor
..............................

Comment: Have you taken a look at the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions)? Please share more details regarding the connection? Are you trying to connect through Private IP, Public IP? Are you managing the connections properly? I notice that you are using a connection pool. But is your code properly [opening and closing the connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#opening_and_closing_connections). Please post a minimum, reproducible example to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

have a look  if your database is running.
I've had the same problem when i forgot to start up my database instance on google cloud.